# Use span element inside a details element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use span element to highlight a word in a html details tag body like bellow :

(highlighted class is nothing but a class with background color)

```
<details>
        <summary>58046</summary>
        Thanks <span class="highlighted">Larry</span> C.
</details>
```

but in exchange I get raw text for this tag in browser. So how can I highlight certain word inside this tag?

edit : by raw text I mean something like picture bellow :
[image]

edit 2 : I am using javascript to make details tag body.

```
function showResult(results) {
    const resultElement = document.getElementById('result');
    for (const item of results) {
        const content = item.content.replaceAll()
        resultElement.innerHTML += `<details class="card single-result">
        <summary>${item.name}</summary>
        ${content}
        </details>`;
    }
}

function highlightWords(content) {
    let newContent = content;
    for (const word of includeWordsList) {
        let regex = new RegExp(word, 'ig');
        newContent.replaceAll(regex, `<span class="highlighted">${word}</span>`);
    }
    return newContent;
}
```

Comment: `.highlighted {background:yellow}`works, what's the trouble here ?

Comment: You could also use HTML `mark`.

Comment: everything looks as expected https://codepen.io/fedeghe/pen/VwayYEN

Comment: What you're seeing is caused by something sanitizing the HTML tags, probably the templating system you're using.

Comment: You need to clarify your question , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details , because nothing tells you cannot have a span inside details where background cannot be applied. Your screen shot may think of your scrript on server side encoding html tags

Comment: @GuyIncognito what do you mean by templating system? I am actually using java script to make details tag body.

Comment: You need to show that code then.

Comment: so give your javascriipt too, it will explain why this happens

Comment: Not enough code. You need to show the entire process of how `item.content` is created and processed. If you do `console.log(content)` I'm pretty sure it'll show `&lt;span&gt;` instead of the tag.

Comment: Check the edited answer. I did not know the actual format of `results` if it is different change it accordingly to suit you.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be working fine.

Here is an example of your code with `.highlighted` coloured white and given a red background:

```css
.highlighted {
  padding: 3px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

summary {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<details>
<summary>58046</summary>
Thanks <span class="highlighted">Larry</span> C.
</details>
```